# PHP uniqid repeating on every iteration of while loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to populate a column in a mysql database with a unique identifier using a while loop, but uniqid is repeating the same output over and over again.

this is my code:

```
$dblink = mysqli_connect($host,$dbu,$dbp);
$dblink->set_charset("utf8");
$seldb = mysqli_select_db($dblink, $db);

  
$dblink = new mysqli($host, $dbu, $dbp, $db);

    $result = $dblink->query(" SELECT * FROM `mytable` ");


    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        $uniquecode = uniqid();
        $sql = mysqli_query($dblink,"UPDATE `mytable` SET `code`='$uniquecode' ");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try echoing the unique?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts. You're mixing both styles here.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're updating *every* record in each iteration because your `UPDATE` is lacking a `WHERE` clause.

Normally you'd key this like:

```
UPDATE ... SET code=? WHERE id=?
```

Where that locks it to just the row matching `id` or whatever your ID column is called.

> Note: You should avoid `SELECT *` unless you actually need all those columns. Here you don't, you just need ID, so just select that.